# Airplane Mode and Do Not Disturb on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 4 running iOS 6, and Do Not Disturb appears under settings, but Do Not Disturb appears to be ornamental compared to my expectations. More specifically, it at least buzzes when I get a call.

If iPhone's default mode is "push and pull both enabled", and Airplane Mode is "push and pull both disabled," is there a "pull enabled, push disabled" mode? Is that something Do Not Disturb should allow? Or how should Airplane Mode and Do Not Disturb mode be understood for my phone?

Comment: I provided an explanation of Airplane Mode and Do Not Disturb in my answer below, but if it doesn’t answer your question, you may want to rewrite it a bit to clarify what exactly you’re trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Airplane Mode and Do Not Disturb perform different functions, neither of which are directly linked to push notifications, but can affect them.

**Airplane Mode** is a quick-fire way to turn off all the wireless radios (cellular, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, GPS) on the iPhone. You can subsequently turn on the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth radios while still in Airplane mode by going to their respective settings toggles. If you have no data connectivity (*i.e.* cellular data or Wi-Fi), then you can’t receive any data, whether via push or pull. For more details, see Apple’s support article: [iOS: Understanding airplane mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1355).

**Do Not Disturb** mode turns off the tones and vibrations from phone calls, SMS/iMessages, and any other push notifications that are set to alert you. *However*, depending on your settings, some calls may still get through. In the Do Not Disturb settings (*Settings → Notifications → Do Not Disturb*), you can configure some calls from a specific group of contacts (*e.g.* your favourites), and repeat calls (a second call within three minutes of the first) to bypass the block.

Do Not Disturb does not prevent your phone from receiving push notifications or pulling data, it merely silences any alarms about the data. It’s also worth noting that alarms set via the built-in Clock app bypass the DND setting.